# How to consume a WCF service using silverlight without need to cross-domain policy

Tags: wcf, silverlight, rest

I have a RESTful service in the internet but silverlight need cross-domain settings, I need to consume this service using by Silverlight,I have tried a WCF service as a middleware, but unfortunately this didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an util class for server side such as **Util.DoRequest(string address):string**

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx):

return `readStream.ReadToEnd` to your client over WCF RIA Services.(Domain Service Class)

By this way if your server has access this RESTful service or it's already located there you do not need any crossdomain configuration for your `xap`.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (args[0]);

        // Set some reasonable limits on resources used by this request
        request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
        request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;
        // Set credentials to use for this request.
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();

        Console.WriteLine ("Content length is {0}", response.ContentLength);
        Console.WriteLine ("Content type is {0}", response.ContentType);

        // Get the stream associated with the response.
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream ();

        // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        Console.WriteLine ("Response stream received.");
        Console.WriteLine (readStream.ReadToEnd ());
        response.Close ();
        readStream.Close ();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [Javascript Bridge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645076%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). I have not tried this approach but you could use ajax call and then "push" to SL via the JS bridge.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying unknown ways, it is better to place a cross domain policy file in the server. Why you don't need to have a cross domain policy file and client access file in the server? Is there any specific reason for it?

Comment: The server which I use doesn't have such file.

Comment: It will not have such files. You need to add those files

Comment: some servers like cloud storage(S3,Azure storage etc). You simply can't put cross domain policy file over such servers. In such cases,you need to rely on the workarounds. Which means "better" is not always a possible option to go with.